# Loop through resources of resx file in Razor view

Tags: .net, loops, razor, resources, resx

Is that possible?

Something like:

```
<div>

@foreach (string s in Resources.text) {
    <div>@s</div>
}

</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
@foreach (var s in Resources.text) 
   {<div>@s</div> } 
</div>
```

Comment: Care to explain why this is any different from the original code?